# Spring @RequestParameter Not a String Error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have an internal server error with `@RequestParam` annotation and this is the error below:

```
2021-11-19 19:09:46.012 ERROR 68100 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] app.gym.v1.Resource.UserControl          : Required request parameter 'isNonLocked' for method parameter type String is not present
2021-11-19 19:09:46.014  WARN 68100 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'isNonLocked' for method parameter type String is not present]
```

this is the code for the resource that gives the API response for that parameter:

```java
@PutMapping("/update")
public ResponseEntity<User> update(@RequestParam("currentUsername") String currentUsername,
                                   @RequestParam("username") String username,
                                   @RequestParam("email") String email,
                                   @RequestParam("role") String role,
                                   @RequestParam("isActive") String isActive,
                                   @RequestParam("isNonLocked") String isNonLocked) throws UserNotFoundException, UsernameExistException, EmailExistException, IOException {
    User updatedUser = userService.updateUser(currentUsername, username,email, role, Boolean.parseBoolean(isNonLocked), Boolean.parseBoolean(isActive));
    return new ResponseEntity<>(updatedUser, OK);
}
```

The problem is with the `isNotLocked` parameter it said it should be a string but I was parsing it correctly from boolean to string so I don't know what is the issue.

Comment: Please check/share your request payload.

Comment: I put the isNotLocked and isActive to true but it won't be accepted

Comment: it says your request body does not have a value for 'isNonLocked'. Post your request body.

Comment: The error is not due to type conversion, but a missing (by default) mandatory request parameter. You should use `@RequestParam(value="isNonLocked", required=false)` instead

Comment: @MohamadJAlanbaki It probably is a spelling mistake.

Are you sending "isNotLocked", ? Because it is expecting "isNonLocked"

Comment: share your request details. How and what all values you sending that will give a better idea to understand the issue.